# how to set a form's target to a fancybox with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fancybox-2

I have a form:

```
<form id="form" method="GET" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hashKey" value="123" >
    <input type="text"  name="orderID" placeholder="orderid">
    <input type="hidden"  name="currencyCode" value="USD">
    <input type="text"  name="amount" value="10.0">
    <input type="hidden" name="payModel" value="sandbox">   

    <button type="submit" id="payModel" name="payModel" value="sandbox">click to buy</button>
</form>
```

when the form is submitted the values are stored using javascript below

```
$(document).ready(function(){      //selecting the form upon submit
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        var formAction = $(this).attr("action");
        var hash = $("input[name=hashKey]").val();
        var id = $("input[name=orderID]").val();
        var code = $("input[name=currencyCode]").val();
        var amount = $("input[name=amount]").val();
        var pay = $("input[name=payModel]").val();

        var link = formAction+"?hashKey="+hash+"&orderID="+id+"&currencyCode="+code+"&amount="+amount+"&payModel="+pay;

        var testlink = "http://google.com";


        $("#form").attr('target',"_self");
        $("#form").attr('action',testlink);
    }
}
```

the links are working fine, but the thing is i want the final form 'action' to be opened in a fancybox iframe. any idea??

it is very easy to open fancybox with a

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/)

Comment: You will need to post the form via ajax check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069208/jquery-launch-a-fancybox-after-ajax-form-submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like below:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href: link,
    type: 'iframe',
    padding: 0
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried that before it didn't do anthing. i made sure i have both fancybox js and css and the example from fancybox worked.....so still wondering how can i do that

Comment: @mohamed can you share fiddle or codepen link with source code

Comment: thanks a lot for taking your time to look into my problem, really appreciate it. i have always used stackoverflow but never needed to sign up cuz pretty much i find the solutions by others. posted the solution below

Answer (score 0):

i got it!!!

by using the second method from this solution.

[How do I submit the data of a form to an iframe in Fancybox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006201/how-do-i-submit-the-data-of-a-form-to-an-iframe-in-fancybox)

```
       $(function() {

$("#form").submit(function() {

    $form = $(this);

    $.fancybox({
            'title': "form submission",
            'href': $form.attr("action") + "?" + $form.serialize(),
            'type': 'iframe'
    });

    return false;

});
```

});